# Detect client disconnect in dart http server

Tags: dart, httpserver

I am using the dart http server as a mock server to test my flutter app interactions with a real server, I am doing something like this:

```
    final _server = await HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, 0);
    _server.listen(handleRequest, onError: (error) {
      print("onError");
    }, onDone: () {
      print("Closed");
    });
```

One of my test cases includes the user canceling a long-running request. I want to test if the request really got canceled and the connection closed.

So I need a way to detect on the server-side if a request has been canceled:

```
void handleRequest(HttpRequest request) async {
    // This future is finished, when the test decides, that the client should have canceled the request
    await waitFuture;
    request.response
      ..statusCode
      ..close():
    // How do I know here if the client has canceled the request in the meantime?
```

Unfortunately, the server seems to simply ignore any client disconnects.

So my question: Is there a way I can detect client disconnects using darts HTTP server?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortantly I did not

Comment: Facing the same problem, any solutions?